# BRST quantization: Explicit computation request

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, brst

Following Green, Schwarz and Witten's book on Superstrings, the BRST charge is given by $$Q_B = c^i K_i-\frac{1}{2}f_{ij}^{~~~k}c^ic^jb_k\tag{3.2.4}$$ 
with 
$$[K_i, K_j] = f_{ij}^{~~~k}K_k,\tag{3.2.1}$$ 
$$\{c^i, b_j\}=\delta^{i}_j,\tag{3.2.2}$$ 
where the $K_i$ are the generator of the gauge group, $c, b$ are ghosts and anti-ghosts respectively.

Now, the action of the BRST charge on a Yang-Mills gauge field $A^i$ goes like 
$$Q_B A^i = D c^i$$ 
with $D$ being the covariant derivative. I wish to know, how to derive the last expression starting from the definition of the BRST charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The [Dirac conjecture](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=dirac+conjecture) states that the generators $K_i$ of the gauge group are given by the [first-class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint), i.e. Gauss law $(D\cdot E)_i$. OP's last equation then follows by recalling the [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) for the conjugate pair $A^i$ and $E_j$. (Here [deWitt's condensed notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation) is assumed everywhere.)

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.